# What is the logic behind this program?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, inner-classes, data-conversion

the operator int() function converts the string to an int

```
class mystring
{ 
  private:
    chat str[20];

  public:
   operator int()             // i'm assuming this converts a string to an int
   {
     int i=0,l,ss=0,k=1;

     l = strlen(str)-1;
     while(l>=0)
     {
       ss=ss+(str[l]-48)*k;
       l--;
       k*=10;
     }
     return(ss);
   } 
}

int main()
{
  mystring s2("123");
  int i=int(s2);
  cout << endl << "i= "<<i;
}
```

So what's the logic behind `operator int()` ? What's the 48 in there? Can someone explain to  me the algorithm behind the conversion from string to int.

Comment: That program won't compile, fix that first.

Comment: 48 is the ascii code value for the character '0'

Comment: It should be observed that that is not well written code, and the "mystery" 48, and lack of comments are the giveaway.  (Also, we have stringstream for this conversion, or boost)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Lack of comments aren't as much of a problem as terrible variable names.

Comment: Well once you fix teh coding errors, the logic appears to be, I'll definitely get a contract for a maintenance cycle. Looks like a homework answer to me.

Comment: I hope this is somekind of homework assignment - if someone where you work is writing code to parse strings to ints then change jobs...

Comment: In addition to the points mentionned by Mooing Duck and Ben Voigt: what happens if the strings are "-15", "  42" (both legal) or "abc" (illegal)?  This is a good example of how _not_ to do it.

Comment: actually it's a program out of a book, and the book isn't bad(before u say it). And of course this isn't the entire program, there were comments and other stuff that i didnt type, i jst wrote the confusing part.

Comment: @Nirvan: Why don't you give more context? What is your intention? Which book? Bad question, -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this converts a string to an integer. 48 is the ASCII value for '0'. If you subtract 48 from an ASCII digit you'll get the value of the digit (ex: '0' - 48 = 0, '1' - 48 = 1, ..). For each digit, your code calculates the correct power of 10 by using `k` (ranges between 1...10^{  log of the number represented by the input string}).

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed convert a string to an integer.  The routine assumes that all characters are decimal digits (things like minus sign, space, or comma will mess it up).

It starts with the ones place and moves through the string.  For each digit, it subtracts off the ASCII value of `'0'`, and multiplies by the current place value.

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed convert the string to an integer.  If you look at an ascii table the numbers start at the value 48.  Using this logic (and lets say the string "123") the while loop will do:

```
l=2

ss=0+(51-48)*1
```

so in this case ss = 3

next loop we get

```
l=1

ss=3+(50-48)*10
```

so ss = 23

next loop

```
l=0
ss=23+(49-48)*100
```

so ss= 123

The loop breaks and we return an integer of value 123.

Hope this helps!